# Show a button when either Button A or Button B is selected. HTML/CSS/JScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, show

Am new to coding and am trying to create a simple code for button selection.

A user is given two choices onload, and upon selecting either Button A **OR** Button B, another button appears (Let's Go!) which will take the user to a different page.

The problem I have with my current code is that Button A and Button B ends up toggling hide/show for the "Let's Go" Button. Its not supposed to do that because **"Let's Go!" should appear upon the first selection and show throughout instead of toggling between hide/show**.

Am open and appreciate any and all advice you might have on how to achieve my intended outcome for the code. Thank you so much for your time!

My codes are below:

```js
  function showLetsGoBtn() {
    var x = document.getElementById("letsGoBtn");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  background:#ddd;
  font-family: "Raleway";
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*  Start popup container */
.popup {
  width:600px;
  height:696px;
  padding:30px 20px;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:justified;
}
/*  End popup container */

.popup .title {
  margin:5px 0px;
  font-size:24px;
  font-weight:600;
}

.popup .description{
  color:#222;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:5px;
}



/* - Start btnA -*/
.popup .btnA {
  margin-top:10px;
}

.popup .btnA button {
  background:#f5f5f5;
  color:#0C59AC;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:600;
  border-radius:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 202px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align:center;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #0C59AC;
}

.popup .btnA button:focus {
  color:#f5f5f5;
  background:#0C59AC;
  opacity: 100%;
}
/* - End btnA -*/



/* - Start btnB -*/
.popup .btnB {
  margin-top:20px;
}

.popup .btnB button {
  background:#f5f5f5;
  color:#0C59AC;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:600;
  border-radius:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 202px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align:center;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #0C59AC;
}

.popup .btnB button:focus {
  color:#f5f5f5;
  background:#0C59AC;
  opacity: 100%;
}
/* End btnB */



/* Start letsGo */
.popup .letsGo {
  margin-top:20px;  
}

.popup .letsGo button {
  background:#0C59AC;
  color:#f5f5f5;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:600;
  border-radius:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 202px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #0C59AC;
}
/* End letsGo */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>showBtnOnClick</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Setup divs for modal.-->
  <div class="popup center">

    <div class="title">
      Click Any Button
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <h5>Intention:</h5>
      <ol>
        <li><strong>Let's Go!</strong> Btn hidden on-load.</li>
        <li>Button A & Button B change colour onclick (blue)</li>
        <li><mark><strong>Let's Go!</strong> Btn appears when either Button A or Button B is clicked (blue).</mark></li>
      </ol>
      <h5>Problem with Current Code:</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>For point 3, my code toggles hide/show for <strong>Let's Go!</strong>
          <br>
          <strong>Let's Go!</strong> is to always show once the user selects either Button A or B at the start.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="btnA">
      <button  onclick="showLetsGoBtn()">
        Button A
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="btnB">
      <button onclick="showLetsGoBtn()">
        Button B
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="letsGo" id=letsGoBtn style="display: none;">
      <button>
        Let's Go!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, remove the else-part from your function and the code within. You never want the button to disappear again, so you don't need that code.

So your code should be:

```
function showLetsGoBtn() {
    var x = document.getElementById("letsGoBtn");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
```

The if-part says: if your button is hidden show it. And the else part says: if your button is not hidden hide it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="letsGo" style="display: none;">
  <button>
    Let's Go!
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting AJ.

I attempted your solution but unfortunately it didn't work. Will take a look again to see how this can be applied. Perhaps a code somewhere else is interrupting the solution from running as intended.

Thanks again!